# Insert Last Primary Key from One Table into Another as Foreign Key

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to find a method for inserting the last primary key from `Table1` as a foreign key into `Table2`.

So far, I have tried `SELECT max(‘id‘) FROM table1 as foreign_key blablablablablabla`

It works if one user registers at that current time; however, if 5 users register at the same time, the foreign key is wrong.

Comment: Please post your full code. I think all PHP database interfaces provide some functionality for that, eg, PDO has [`PDO::lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways you can do this.

#### Creating a trigger

You can create a trigger after insert of `table1` into `table2`. For example;

```
CREATE TRIGGER `add to other table` AFTER INSERT ON `table1`
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO table2 SET user_id=NEW.id, name=NEW.username;
```

#### Using PHP

You can do this using [**`mysqli::insert_id`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php), for example; (You would bind and sanitize input, but for the sake of illustration, I won't)

```
 $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `table1` SET `username`='pokrenz'");
 $intForeignKey = $mysql->insert_id;
 $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `table2` SET `id` = ". $intForeignKey);
```